# iOS: How to correctly implement custom gesture recognizer in super class?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer, gesture-recognition

the buttons in my iOS8+ app should react by painting an outline around the buttons as long as the user presses the finger on it. The goal is to encapsulate this behaviour into the `OutlineButton` class (cp. below class hierarchy). When releasing the finger, the app should execute the defined action (mostly perform a segue to another view controller). Here's my current class hierarchy for this purpose:

```
 - UIButton
  |_ OutlineButton
    |_ FlipButton
```

The FlipButton class perform some fancy flip effect and additionally I have a category on UIView for drop shadow, rounded corners and the outlines.

Currently I have the following additional class:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TouchDownGestureRecognizer : UIGestureRecognizer

@end
```

... and the corresponding implementation:

```
#import "UIView+Extension.h"
#import "TouchDownGestureRecognizer.h"

@implementation TouchDownGestureRecognizer

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [self.view showOutline]; // this is a function in the UIView category (cp. next code section)
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [self.view hideOutline]; // this is a function in the UIView category (cp. next code section)
}

@end
```

... this is the relevant snippet of the UIView+Extension.m category for painting the outline on the buttons:

```
- (void)showOutline {
    self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
}

- (void)hideOutline {
    self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
}
```

... and in the OutlineButton.m file I have the following so far:

```
#import "OutlineButton.h"

@implementation OutlineButton

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self addGestureRecognizer:[[TouchDownGestureRecognizer alloc] init]];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Visually, this works fine, as soon as a button is touched an outline is drawn and hidden again as soon as the finger is released. But the IBAction's and segues that are connected to these buttons via storyboard are performed after a huge delay (around 2 seconds) if at all. The actions are also performed multiple times if the button was pressed more than once (...after a long delay). Really strange behaviour...

Somebody any ideas how to solve this issue?

**SOLUTION (based on matt's answer, thanks):**

```
#import "OutlineButton.h"
#import "UIView+Extension.h"

@implementation OutlineButton

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self addTarget:self action:@selector(showOutline) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [self addTarget:self action:@selector(hideOutline) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside | UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the buttons in my iOS8+ app should react by painting an outline around the buttons as long as the user presses the finger on it

The most framework-compliant way to implement that is to assign to the button, for the highlighted state, an image that has the outline. It is while the button is being pressed that it is being highlighted; therefore, it is while the button is being pressed that it will display the outline.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. If there's another way than making an image for the outline, I would prefer that... The implementation suggested by you might be simple, but managing images for each possible sizes my buttons will have ends up in a mess. So, another approach like described in the question would be highly appreciated. Do custom gesture recognizers in super classes really mess up the responder chain that hard?

Comment: You're just being silly. No "image" needs to be "managed". Look at the screencast in my answer. No "image" is used here; the rectangle was created and assigned in code, based on the size of the button.

Comment: Okay I got it, your phrasing was a bit awkward... I extended my question with the correct code snippet based on your answer. Thanks.